# Dataflow: SDK harness disconnected errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, etl, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have a pipeline to extract embeddings (feature vectors) from `images` stored in Cloud Storage bucket and insert into a BigQuery table.

We're consistently getting `SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected.` errors when the Dataflow job runs on **N1** type VM instances.

```
Error message from worker: 
Data channel closed, unable to send additional data to SDK sdk-0-3
SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected.
SDK harness sdk-0-2 disconnected.
SDK harness sdk-0-0 disconnected.
Data channel closed, unable to receive additional data from SDK sdk-0-3
SDK harness sdk-0-1 disconnected.
SDK harness sdk-0-2 disconnected.
Data channel closed, unable to receive additional data from SDK sdk-0-1
```

**Notes**

**N2** machines work fine but **N1** fails somewhat surprising because **N1** is Google-default machine.

- Jobs run slower on **N1** machines and sometimes appear to fail due to these errors.
- Using a larger VM (more memory, CPU and disk) didn't resolve the errors.
- We also have *another* pipeline to extract embeddings from `text` and using [lapse](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/LaBSE) model which has the same errors on both **N1** and **N2** machines
- Diagnostics tab: `No errors found during this interval.`

We're creating DF job templates (Apache Beam 2.40 Python), storing them on Cloud Storage and using API to launch new jobs.

- We're **batching** the items before giving them to the stage where embeddings are extracted. Reducing batch size didn't matter.
- Pipeline option `sdk_worker_parallelism` changed from 0 (default) to 1 and didn't change anything.
- **Auto-scaling** disabled (`max_worker=1`) and same errors.
- **Reshuffle** stage removed from the pipe

  - There are disconnect errors e.g. `SDK harness sdk-0-0 disconnected.`
    but no data channel errors e.g. `The Data channel closed, unable to send additional data to SDK sdk-0-3`

Answer (score 0):

This error message could be due to a wide variety of causes which cannot be easily detected unless the error message is accompanied by the other behavior. This error could be due to any number of listed errors in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors).

For getting more information about the error, it can be investigated in the Diagnostics table which can be seen in the below image.
The [Diagnostics table](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshooting-your-pipeline#Workflow) shows the timeline and possible recommendations for your pipeline for the errors that occurred. You can view the [job metrics](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-monitoring-intf#accessing_job_monitoring_charts) to monitor your Dataflow Jobs.

[image]

Comment: Diagnostics tab: `No errors found during this interval.`

Comment: Hi @tokman, can you check the `JOB LOGS`?